# How to make the map view pitched downwards in HERE maps in Android?

Tags: android, dictionary, here-api

It's a simple question, but I could not find the information online.

In Street Level, `ARController` can be used to achieve downwards representation. This is the so called CAMERA view.

My question is: **How can I make the map view pitched downwards in MAP View (not in CAMERA view)?** The view should be from up to down with an angle around the x-axis.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi All. This information may solve this problem.  **map.setTilt(45);**  // Set the tilt to 45 degrees

Answer (score 0):

To set the tilt (pitch) of the `Map` you can use the `Map#setTilt(float)` method.

There are also compound operations available for changing the state of the Map such as `Map#setCenter(PointF newCenter, Animation animation, double zoomLevel,float orientation, float tilt)`

The StreetLevel (i.e. StreetView) feature is controlled using the `StreetLevelModel` object. To change the pitch of a StreetLevel scene, use the `StreetLevelModel#setPitch(float)` function.

When using the LiveSight (Augmented Reality) feature, by default the `Map` state is controlled automatically using device sensor information. In this case, tilt (pitch) will be adjusted automatically. To disable the default behaviour and allow calls to `Map#setTilt()` to work, call `ARController#DownViewParams#setAutoPitchEnabled(false, false)`

see also: [HERE Maps Android Developer Guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/overview.html)